# Is there any advantage/disadvantage to using function delegates over lambdas in a collection?

Tags: visual-c++, lambda, delegates, c++11

I am at that really boring part in the development of my library, where I want to construct a class based on a windows message identifier and the `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` arguments.  The prototype for such functions is trivial:

```
boost::shared_ptr<EventArgs>(const UINT& _id, const WPARAM& _w, const LPARAM& _l);
```

For each windows message, I will have a function of this nature.

Now, what I am currently doing is using the [FastDelegate](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx) library to do my delegates.  These are stored in a map thusly:

```
typedef fastdelegate::FastDelegate3<const UINT&, const WPARAM&, const LPARAM&, boost::shared_ptr<EventArgs> > delegate_type;
typedef std::map<int, delegate_type> CreatorMap;
```

And when a windows message needs to have an `EventArg`-derived class created, it's a simple case of looking up the appropriate delegate, invoking it and returning the newly-created instance nicely contained in a `shared_ptr`.

```
boost::shared_ptr<EventArgs> make(const UINT& _id, const WPARAM& _w, const LPARAM& _l) const
 {
  MsgMap::const_iterator cit(m_Map.find(_id));
  assert(cit != m_Map.end());
  boost::shared_ptr<EventArgs> ret(cit->second(_w, _l));
  return ret;
 }; // eo make
```

All is working fine.  But then I was thinking, rather than having all these delegates around, why not take advantage of lambdas in C++0x?  So, I quickly prototyped the following:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::function<boost::shared_ptr<EventArgs>(const WPARAM&, const LPARAM&)> > MapType;
typedef MapType::iterator mit;

MapType map;
map[WM_WHATEVER] = [](const WPARAM& _w, const LPARAM& _l) { /* create appropriate eventargs class given parameters */ };
map[WM_ANOTHER] = ....;
// and so on
```

Once again, it's simple to look up and invoke:

```
mit m = map.find(WM_PAINT);
boost::shared_ptr<EventArgs> e(m->second(_wParam, _lParam));
// dispatch e
```

Is there an advantage to using lambdas in this way?  I know the overhead of looking up the right delegate/lambda will be the same (as both types of map are keyed with an `int`), but I am aiming to dispatch my messages from the wndProc in my nice C++ friendly-way as efficiently as possible.  My gut-feeling is that lambdas will be faster, but unfortunately i lack the experience in understanding compiler-optimizations to make a judgement call on this, hence my question here :)  Oh, and in keeping with the topic of the question, are there any gotchas/something I haven't thought about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two real differences here:

The first is how you store the callback: Either the fast-delegate or std::function. The latter is based on boost::function, and fast delegates were specifically designed to outperform those. However, std::function is standard conforming, while fast delegates are not.

The other difference is the way you setup your code, and I see a clear advantage for lambdas here. You can write the actual code exactly where it matters, you don't need to define a separate function that only serves a niche-purpose.

If you want raw speed - fast-delegates probably win (but you should benchmark, if that is an argument), but if you want readability and standard conformity, go with std::function and lambdas.

Comment: thanks for your response and you're right.  `fastdelegate` (which I have used before) are, indeed, very good performance-wise.  But again, as you point out, using lambdas I can create a very readable map-initialization with anonymous functions that, as you also point out, serve a single purpose.  And as you say, I don't know at this point whether performance is going to be an issue!